# What if the universe were started in macrostate with maximal microstate?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, time

We know if you start with hundred coins with a head on the top, and start tossing them then after sufficient time a macrostate will be achieved for which the number of microstates is maximum. This lets us see the increase in entropy.

This increase in entropy also helps see the arrow of time. The universe started with a big bang, it was compact and orderly. Then since then, the entropy is increasing and we see time moving forward in this sense.  What if the universe had started in macrostate with maximal microstate? Does it look the same as now?

Comment: Well, no. Like said in the answers here, the Universe would have started as blackholium. Since $dS/dt \geq 0$, that blackholium would remain blackholium, barring Hawking radiation (which is negligible where M equals the Universe's total mass-energy).

Comment: ... and besides: a black hole's event horizon is a 2D object (a 2-sphere). The Universe, spatially, is a 3D object (a 3-sphere).  Topologically, it's not the same thing at all. Any answers suggesting otherwise are comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 2):

In his book "Cycles of Time" (it can also be found in "Road to Reality") from Roger Penrose he states that the universe already started in a macrostate with maximal number microstates (if gravitation is neglected).

How is this possible ?
The best picture we can get from the start of the universe (also called Big Bang) is the cosmic microwave background radiation shortly called CMB.
The spectrum of CMB was very precisely measured and was found the best black-body radiation spectrum ever found. Therefore one must conclude that the matter at the beginning of the universe was in perfect thermal equilibrium, i.e. with a maximum number of microstates --- or in different words with a maximum of entropy.

So does this fit with the 2nd law of thermodynamics ? One aspect was neglected, namely gravitation. The effect of gravitation was not yet thermalized at the big-bang. Penrose makes the curious observation that contrary to  a gas that spreads out if it is at the beginning held in a small corner of a large box, the effect of gravitation starts from a homogeneous distribution of matter which in the following agglomerates to form galaxies, stars and planets and finally also black holes. And an increase of entropy goes along with this development. This can be seen above all at the final endpoint of this development, in the creation of many black holes which are containers of a huge amount of entropy according to the formula of Bekenstein & Hawking which I cite setting all physical constants to 1:

$$S = \frac{A}{4}$$

where $S$ is the entropy and $A$ the surface of the black hole.
Actually the entropy of a black hole outweighs all other forms of thermalizations, it has the largest entropy of everything.
So when you ask how would have started an universe in a macrostate with maximal microstate, so taking correctly gravitation into account, this universe start would simply be a super huge black hole.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

R. Penrose stresses that the universe actually started from very special conditions, and these are related to gravitation. It started from a state that developed into a FLRW universe which is very homogeneous and isotropic as observations proof.  As far as I understood it could have started from a more complicated curvature distribution than just constant curvature $K$ leading to a FLRW universe. So it could have started from a structure involving several (or even many) black holes. So it would have started with a much larger number of microstates than it actually did. If it were like this there would be still time development as the entropy can still increase.

However, if the universe had "started" from a unique black hole  (extreme case) which gathers most of the microstates compared to anything else, the entropy would be at its possible maximum and the time development would not exist.

**EDIT**

One has to realize that if one "starts" with a universe which is in a macrostate which has the maximum number of microstates, it turns out to be a dead universe.

The entropy is the logarithm (being a monotonous function) of the number of microstates, if they are at maximum, the entropy is also at maximum. As time arrow is given by the increase of the entropy, there will be no time arrow or better said no time whatsoever, because the entropy is at its maximum and cannot increase further. This means that this macrostate being the whole universe does not show any development, so in other words, the universe is dead. So this state would actually better describe a possible end of the universe not the beginning.

Anyway, the question is completely hypothetical, our universe did not start from such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Tossing the coins means coupling them to the external world (*thermostat* in statistical physics language), which mixes the microstates - note that the number of microstates does not change (unless we allow coins to be added or removed), what changes is the probability of finding the system in a specific microstate.

Universe is probably better viewed as a *closed system*... although it is not certain that one can apply this notion to the system which is the only system in the Universe... In any case, the comparison requires more clarification (I feel that there may be a real question behind, but it needs to be better formulated.)

Answer (score 0):

If the universe had started in macrostate with maximal entropy, then yes, it would have remained in that macrostate indefinitely. There would be no macroscopically observable arrow of time; the only distinction between the past and the future would be reflected in subtle microscopic asymmetries involving the weak nuclear force, but no macroscopic experimental apparatus (including humans) would be able to exist in order to observe these asymmetries.